# Is the following hash function construction collision resistant?

Tags: collision-resistance, pseudo-random-generator

### The problem

Let the following function be a collision reisistant hash function
$$H=\{H_s:\{0,1\}^{2n} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{n} \}$$
Let the following function be a PRG
$$G:\{0,1\}^{n+1} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{2n}$$
Is the following costrunction a collision resistant hash function?
$$H^*(x) = H_s(G(x))$$

#### My solution

My intuition tells me that this must not be a collision resistant hash function, because an attacker can choose the seed of the PRG (the seed is the message that the attacker want to hash). If we let G be a PRG such that finding a "collision" in G can be done with probability better then negligeble, then the above construction is not collision resistant.

Comment: You should go from the contrapositive; assume that $H^*$ is not collision resistant then, you can find two distinct inputs that either have the same output from $G$ with $G$ you can find collision for the $H$...

Comment: @kelalaka I think i am not following you...

Comment: Direct proof, in general hard, so you should go for the contrapositive and derive that either H is not a collision-resistant or G is not PRG.

Comment: @kelalaka to prove that is a collision resistant hash yes, but to say that in general this is not a collision resistant hash function i just need to show a counterexample. I think the PRG i described above should prove thath this is not a collision resistant. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I think, the domain of the PRG is a hint to what can cause issues. Consider starting with a $n$-bit secure PRG, then sabotage it in a way that it becomes a $n+1$ bit PRG which is still secure as a PRG, but allows  collisions in the hash construction.

Comment: Yeh, @MarcIlunga gave the full hint.

Comment: @kelalaka, do you mean as in this is a spoiler to a potential homework? :-/

Comment: @MarcIlunga Usually, we go step by step, show the pitfalls, and see the efforts so that they drive the conclusion themselves. Normally, my next hint was what is PRG?

Comment: @kelalaka, I agree with the step-by-step approach and I try to usually do this. But in this case, my reading of "my solution" suggests that they were on a good path where they can benefit more from a hint related to where they are rather than a generic one. But I am okay to be wrong about this : )

Comment: I think i got it. If we consider the PRG such that n=3, then the stretch will be 4. Now this PRG leaks 2 bits of the seed. so the first 2 bits of the output are the first 2 bits of the seed itself. The last 2 bits of the output can be either 1 or 0. Now i can find a collision with high probability like this: G(110) = 11xx, G(111) = 11yy. if xx = yy i found a collision and xx=yy can happen with 1/4 of probability. Am i right?

Comment: @zBION1C you are going on the hard way. What if PRG discards it's one bit?